# ServiceStack cache size

Tags: servicestack

In ServiceStack when using IN-memory cache is there a way to find the actual size of the cached objects in bytes?

Answer (score 0):

The [In Memory Cache](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/CacheAccess.Providers/MemoryCacheClient.cs) just stores everything in a `ConcurrentDictionary`. There's no available way to count the bytes.

One solution would be to create your own fork of it and add all the instrumentation you need on each write.